# Logical interpretation question

Tags: logic

I've been given an assignment on logic but since I've never done anything similar before so I'm pretty unsure of my solution. Could anyone more experienced than me please have a look?

The task is: **For the following sentence, give a logical interpretation that makes the sentence true and a logical interpretation that makes the sentence false**

∀x[Q(x,f(x,a)) → R(g(x))]

To make the sentence true I need to make the part before implication false, so I would use the following interpretation:

U = N, a = 6, Q = {(x,y) ∈ N x N, x mod y = 0}, R = {x ∈ N, x >= 0}, f(x,y) = x + y, g(x) = x

To make the sentence false I need the sentence to be in 1 → 0 shape, so I would use the following interpretation:

U = N, a = 1, Q = {(x,y) ∈ N x N, y >= x}, R = {x ∈ N, x >= 0}, f(x,y) = x + y, g(x) = x * (-1)

I'm mainly unsure about the first part of the sentence, so I'd rather ask here about it. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To make the sentence true I need to make the part before implication false, ...

No, there is no *need* to make the antecedent false (although that is one way to accomplish it, sure). But another way is to make the consequent true, and with your R being the whole domain, you're good there.

Note that the same is true for your second interpretation, and so that interpretation would seem to make the sentence true as well ... if it weren't for the fact that that interpretation is not a valid interpretation in the first place:  your $q$ is not well defined, since it gives you negative numbers that are not in your domain.

With these kinds of questions, it's sometimes easier to just use a very limited domain and well-defined yet otherwise meaningless functions and relations. So, for example, you could just say:

$U = \{ 0 \}$

$g(0)=0$

$f(0,0)=0$

$Q = \{ <0,0> \}$

And now you can set:

$R =  \{ 0 \}$

to make the statement true, and:

$R =  \{ \}$

to make the statement false

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased that better, I didn't need to make the part false, I meant that that was one of the ways to make the sentence true. I see where I made the mistake, thank you for your help, your post really helped me understand this matter.

Comment: @khand Glad I could help :)